# Javascript music player acting weird

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio-player

I have multiple issues with the following code.

```
<audio id="player" autoplay loop >
    <source id="mp3Source" src="" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

<script>
var vid = document.getElementById('player');
vid.volume = 0.3;
function loadSong(songNo) {
    var mp3Source = document.getElementById('mp3Source');
    mp3Source.src = 'songs/' + songNo + '.mp3';
};
$(window).keydown(function(evt) {
    if (evt.which == 107) {
        if (vid.volume < 1) {
            vid.volume = Math.max( Math.ceil((vid.volume + 0.1) * 10) / 10)
        }
    }
    if (evt.which == 109) {
        if (vid.volume > 0) {
            vid.volume = Math.max( Math.ceil((vid.volume - 0.1) * 10) / 10)
        }
    }
    if (evt.which == 32) {
        vid.volume = 0
    }
    if (evt.which == 97) {
        loadSong(1)
    }
    if (evt.which == 98) {
        loadSong(2)
    }
});
</script>
```

Now, first issue being when you play with the keys (+ / -), when you press + a few times and then spam - the vid.volume will get stuck at same float number and won't go below that number but it will still go above. Second issue is that I can rarely hear music play in browser, it seems like it's random? I am not sure if there's something wrong with my code or it's the way thing has to work.

To sum up issues, when playing with keys (-) key will get stuck and volume won't decrease and when opening .html file the music does not play in browser, only plays randomly (if you refresh or relaunch file)

Comment: If you need to manipulate audio, instead of an audio element I recommend using the [audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto I'm not sure what you mean by that exactly as the Audio API is a set of tools to work with media in web pages, the primary elements of which are `<audio>` and `<video>`...

Comment: You don't need elements to use the audio API ... check this examples https://github.com/mdn/webaudio-examples. You can create an audio context and manipulate it in any way you want. Take a closer look and ask me if you find any trouble.The important thing is to save your loaded audio instead of reloading it everytime (you could do this with multiple audio elements but it's a bit messy)

Comment: Also, I just notice you are using `Math.max` with only one parameter. Here is a good explanation of how it works [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)